# How to run different website in a same domain with HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, laravel, http, https, dns

Can i run different websites in same domain. like

```
http://www.example.com ----> in WordPress
https://example.com/ -----> in laravel
```

Here is the reference site

```
Website : www.linqs.in              
APP:    https://linqs.in/username
```

App url will open user's profile by provided username.

sorry if i made mistake !! if this possible please guide me.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do that?

Comment: @Mathew Daly did you check the reference site i mentioned in post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your [virtual host configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html):

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/wordpress"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/laravel/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also need to define directories if the sources are not under your default http root. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/laravel"
    <Directory /path/to/laravel>
          AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will also allow Apache to serve that directory and use any .htaccess files (if it wasn't allowed already).

Comment: instead of doing that,  can i use 'www.example.com' and 'https://example.com' ? do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: What you set as a server name in each configuration is up to you. The webserver will respond to requests on that port requesting the specific server name.

Answer (score 0):

Since URL listen on port like http - port 80, https - port 443. So, you can ensure different website in a same domain via VirtualHost configure.

Comment: can you give me some example ?

Comment: please check it, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html